# If time expires does it still count against a down conversion rate?

Tags: american-football, statistics

Sorry for the bad title, didn't really know how to title it.

If a team is 4-4 on 3rd down conversions, it is a 3rd down and time expires does that count against the conversion rate? Same for end of the game... 3rd down clock runs out and there is no time left in the game, does it count against the 6 out of 6 for 3rd down conversion?

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A third-down conversion attempt occurs when a team runs a third-down play and either succeeds in getting the first down (or a touchdown), or fails and goes to fourth down.

The clock doesn't stop a play; if the clock runs to 0, the half ends when the play is over.  So if the clock runs out before the third-down play begins, then no third-down attempt has occurred.  If the clock runs to 0 while the third-down play is taking place, then it will count as an attempt, and it will be a successful attempt if it ends in a first down or a touchdown, and a failure if it does not.

One other thing to note about third-down efficiency statistics: If the first down is achieved as a result of a penalty, then it does not count as an attempt for statistics purposes.

The rules for determining third-down efficiency are defined in the [NCAA Football Statisticians' Manual](http://www.ncaa.org/championships/statistics/ncaa-football-statisticians-manual).  From the 2013 Basic Interpretations section:

> **THIRD-DOWN EFFICIENCY** — Third-down efficiency is the success a team has in converting third-down rushing or passing plays to first
>   downs or touchdowns. If a first down is obtained by penalty on a
>   third-down play or if a field goal is attempted on third down, the
>   offensive team is not charged with an attempt in determining
>   efficiency.